# How to apply plugin from root directory in kotlin dsl

Tags: kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-dsl

I have a plugin with the name of `jacoco-report.gradle.kts` in root directory of project(ProjectName/jacoco-report.gradle.kts). Now I want to add this plugin inside the plugins block of submodules.

```
plugins{
    //id of jacoco-report.gradle.kts
}
```

Can someone please help me how can I apply this plugin. Before migrating to kotlin dsl, I used `apply from: rootProject.file("jacoco-report.gradle")` to apply this plugin in groovy gradle file.

Answer (score 3):

Finally I found a way to do this.

```
rootProject.apply {
    rootProject.file("jacoco-report.gradle.kts")
}
```